# Right way to "pause" the network interface controller on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, lan, network-adapter, tcpip

I have machine with Windows 7 and with ethernet NIC (network card).

I want to interrupt data flow (like when I pull out the network cable).
But I do not want Windows to stop network stack (network services). In other words, I need all those "127.0.0.1" and similar "things" to run ;-).

I tried to turn off Network Adapter in Windows (in Control panel in network connections). But this suspend some of the network stack/function of the operating system either.

Comment: change the ip address to something invalid, and remove the gateway address? by invalid I mean not on the network

Comment: A Software firewall will do it. I use [WIndows Firewall Control](http://www.binisoft.org/wfc.php) You can set the profile to "High Filtering" which blocks all inbound and outbound connections.

Comment: @RichieFrame: it is not easy (as both removing the cable and suppressing the LAN connection are)

Comment: @moab: ok, as I see, it is probably only one solution (except writing own utility ;-) )